# Does jQuery mouseup event work on touch devices?

Tags: jquery, mouseup

I couldn't find any answer so I'm asking here. Currently I don't own any touch devices so I can't test it.

The following code hides all subcontainers in a container if clicked outside of it.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $('#container');
  if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
  {
    $('.subcontainer').hide();
  }
});
```

Does this work on touch devices or there is any equivalent of `mouseup` for touch devices?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, it does not work. But here is a `touchstart` and `touchend` event.

```
$(document).bind( "mouseup touchend", function(e){
  var container = $('#container');
  if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
  {
    $('.subcontainer').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I bind to $('body') or $(document)?

Comment: You can do both if your html is valid with a body tag.

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky always attach to it parent element.  This will enhance the DOM search

Comment: Thanks! So attaching bind to `body` will be faster, because `#container` is a child of `body` :)

Comment: but touch events are not supported on IE, Edge, nor Safari

Answer (score 0):

To bring this thread up-to-date (i.e. 2019), note that jQuery deprecated
'bind' as of version 3.

Today when I first-tested a 'thumb-slider' (i.e. input element, type='range')
on Android, it failed, because my event-functions named only mousemove and
and mouseup respectively.

I simply changed them to:

$('#sliderID').on('touchmove mousemove', function(event){  ... }
    and
$('#sliderID').on('touchend mouseup', function(event){ ... }
and now the webapp works on both PC(Windows-10) and Android(v7.1)
My jQuery version is 3.3.1.

(These are the only two platforms I have available to me for testing, but I'm confident that this works in all major browsers.  I've been successful on Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and Edge-on-Win10)