# How to create an event and get the highlighted text on selection of texts in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the thing...
In desktop browsers I used `document.selection.createRange()` and `window.getSelection();` to get the highlighted text. And, I used `onmouseup` event to create an event on the selection of texts. **Both are working on desktop platforms**

But in Mobile browsers `onmouseup` event not working...

So what should I use instead of `onmouseup` event for smartphones

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135736/does-jquery-mouseup-event-work-on-touch-devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `taphold` event for smartphones and also use [jquery mobile](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/) to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile there is no mouse. These need to be replaced with touch and scroll events. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)