# add multiple event types to an event listener in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand how to best do this.

I have a slideshow where I have a div that keep track of what slide it's on.

I need to have keep a consistent count on both clicks of previous and next arrows, and drag on both desktop and mobile.

This question is related to drag on both desktop mobile. Because mousedown doesn't translate to mobile I need to figure how to use touch events too within an event listener and despite 3 attempts and research I don't get it.

My initial attempt is below:

```
function nextSlideHandler(){
            slideCounter = (slideCounter+1)%{$slides_size};
            $('#slide-text').replaceWith({$slide_text});
            $('#slide-top-section').replaceWith({$slide_top_section});
       }

       function previousSlideHandler(){
            slideCounter = (slideCounter+{$slides_size}-1)%{$slides_size};
            $('#slide-text').replaceWith({$slide_text});
            $('#slide-top-section').replaceWith({$slide_top_section});
       }

var swipeElement = $('.n2-ss-swipe-element')[0];
        var isDown = false;
       var direction = '';
        swipeElement.addEventListener('mousedown, touchend', function(e) {
            isDown = true;
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener('mouseup, touchstart', function(e) {
          isDown = false;
          if(direction == 'left'){
            nextSlideHandler();
            }
           if(direction == 'right'){
              previousSlideHandler();
            }
            direction='';
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener('mousemove, touchmove', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           if (isDown) {
           var deltaX = event.movementX;
           var deltaY = event.movementY;
           if(deltaX>0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'right';
           if(deltaX<0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'left';
         }
        }, true);
```

Thought process - mousedown etc is for desktop while touch events are for mobile and fire if one of those event types happens.

But this does not work. Slide count does not update.

I found https://gomakethings.com/listening-to-multiple-events-in-vanilla-js/ which suggests multiple event listeners

Although pedantic and repetitive I tried spliiting out into multiple event listeners

```
function nextSlideHandler(){
            slideCounter = (slideCounter+1)%{$slides_size};
            $('#slide-text').replaceWith({$slide_text});
            $('#slide-top-section').replaceWith({$slide_top_section});
       }

       function previousSlideHandler(){
            slideCounter = (slideCounter+{$slides_size}-1)%{$slides_size};
            $('#slide-text').replaceWith({$slide_text});
            $('#slide-top-section').replaceWith({$slide_top_section});
       }

   var swipeElement = $('.n2-ss-swipe-element')[0];
    var isDown = false;
   var direction = '';

    swipeElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        isDown = true;
    }, true);

    swipeElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        isDown = true;
    }, true);

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
      isDown = false;
      if(direction == 'left'){
        nextSlideHandler();
        }
       if(direction == 'right'){
          previousSlideHandler();
        }
        direction='';
    }, true);

    document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
      isDown = false;
      if(direction == 'left'){
        nextSlideHandler();
        }
       if(direction == 'right'){
          previousSlideHandler();
        }
        direction='';
    }, true);

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       if (isDown) {
       var deltaX = event.movementX;
       var deltaY = event.movementY;
       if(deltaX>0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'right';
       if(deltaX<0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'left';
     }
    }, true);

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       if (isDown) {
       var deltaX = event.movementX;
       var deltaY = event.movementY;
       if(deltaX>0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'right';
       if(deltaX<0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'left';
     }
    }, true);
```

This doesn't work either.

I found these answers:

[does mousedown /mouseup in jquery work for the ipad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303469/does-mousedown-mouseup-in-jquery-work-for-the-ipad)

[Does jQuery mouseup event work on touch devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135736/does-jquery-mouseup-event-work-on-touch-devices)

[Using mousedown event on mobile without jQuery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144370/using-mousedown-event-on-mobile-without-jquery-mobile)

So far with this research, it seems like I'm on the right track using touch events.

This answer was the most promising: [Binding multiple events to a listener (without JQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796988/binding-multiple-events-to-a-listener-without-jquery) so I took the idea here and rolled with it:

function nextSlideHandler(){
            slideCounter = (slideCounter+1)%{$slides_size};
            $('#slide-text').replaceWith({$slide_text});
            $('#slide-top-section').replaceWith({$slide_top_section});
       }

```
   function previousSlideHandler(){
        slideCounter = (slideCounter+{$slides_size}-1)%{$slides_size};
        $('#slide-text').replaceWith({$slide_text});
        $('#slide-top-section').replaceWith({$slide_top_section});
   }

   function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener) {
        var events = eventNames.split(' ');
        for (var i=0, iLen=events.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        element.addEventListener(events[i], listener, false);
      }
   }

   $('.entry-content').append({$slide_top_section}).append({$slide_text});

   $('#n2-ss-{$id}-arrow-previous').on('click', $.proxy(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
       previousSlideHandler()}, this));

   $('#n2-ss-{$id}-arrow-next').on('click', $.proxy(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
       nextSlideHandler()}, this))

   var swipeElement = $('.n2-ss-swipe-element')[0];
    var isDown = false;
   var direction = '';
    swipeElement.addListenerMulti('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
        isDown = true;
    }, true);

    document.addListenerMulti('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
      isDown = false;
      if(direction == 'left'){
        nextSlideHandler();
        }
       if(direction == 'right'){
          previousSlideHandler();
        }
        direction='';
    }, true);

    document.addListenerMulti('mousemove touchmove', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       if (isDown) {
       var deltaX = event.movementX;
       var deltaY = event.movementY;
       if(deltaX>0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'right';
       if(deltaX<0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'left';
     }
    }, true);
```

After this the slide count still does not update.

How do I combine multiple event types in an event listener?

**UPDATE** Another attempt:

```
   function nextSlideHandler(){
        slideCounter = (slideCounter+1)%{$slides_size};
        $('#slide-text').replaceWith({$slide_text});
        $('#slide-top-section').replaceWith({$slide_top_section});
   }

   function previousSlideHandler(){
        slideCounter = (slideCounter+{$slides_size}-1)%{$slides_size};
        $('#slide-text').replaceWith({$slide_text});
        $('#slide-top-section').replaceWith({$slide_top_section});
   }

   function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener) {
        var events = eventNames.split(' ');
        for (var i=0, iLen=events.length; i<iLen; i++) {
          element.addEventListener(events[i], listener, false);
        }
   }

   $('.entry-content').append({$slide_top_section}).append({$slide_text});

   $('#n2-ss-{$id}-arrow-previous').on('click', $.proxy(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
       previousSlideHandler()}, this));

   $('#n2-ss-{$id}-arrow-next').on('click', $.proxy(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
       nextSlideHandler()}, this))

   var swipeElement = $('.n2-ss-swipe-element')[0];
   var isDown = false;
   var direction = '';
    addListenerMulti(swipeElement, 'mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
        isDown = true;
    }, true);

    addListenerMulti(swipeElement, 'mouseup touchend', function(e) {
      isDown = false;
      if(direction == 'left'){
        nextSlideHandler();
        }
       if(direction == 'right'){
          previousSlideHandler();
        }
        direction='';
    }, true);

    addListenerMulti(swipeElement, 'mousemove touchmove', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       if (isDown) {
       var deltaX = event.movementX;
       var deltaY = event.movementY;
       if(deltaX>0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'right';
       if(deltaX<0 && Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY) && Math.abs(deltaX)>=10) direction = 'left';
       console.log(direction);
     }
    }, true);
```

Comment: Are you not getting errors on that last solution? `addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener)` takes `element` as its first param. But you are passing `.addListenerMulti('mouseup touchend',` Did you mean to do this `addListenerMulti(document, 'my event'`

Comment: Can you add the HTML. Is that possible. The call to addListenerMulti is still wrong, you have an additional param `true`. But that should not hurt. Add a `console.log('in event');` in the function you pass to test it is being triggered. And then test on a PC/Mac before you even try touch.

Answer (score 0):

When we correctly call with the element, it seems to work fine.

```js
 const mySampleListener = (event) => {
  console.log(`Event occured: ${event.target.innerHTML}`);
 }
 
 
 function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener) {
      var events = eventNames.split(' ');
      for (var i=0, iLen=events.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      element.addEventListener(events[i], listener, false);
    }
 }
 
 let events = "click keyup";
 let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.track');
 
 divs.forEach(d => {
  addListenerMulti(d, events, mySampleListener);
 })
```

```html
<div class="track">Div 1</div>
<div  class="track">Div 2</div>
<input type="text"  class="track" />
```

Comment: Okay but this is for multiple divs and I only have one. It doesn't work it says `swipeElement.addListenerMulti is not a function` but I define the function so idk why it says that

Comment: You cannot call it like that, you need to call it `addListenerMulti(swipeElement, 'click keydown etc', myFunction);`

Comment: You function requires you to pass the `element` in as the first parameter. My sample code was just to show how you should use the method

Comment: I implemented your concept and it still doesn't work sorry. I'll update my answer.